# Throw Exception When Parameter Missing Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest

I am new to Python, Django and the Django Rest Framework - although I am loving the learning curve!

I would like to know what is the standard (most common) way of raising an exception when an API's parameter is not provided ?

Obviously *if conditions* in the view's body is not the way to go. Are there an decorators that I can pass parameter names to ?

```
# urls.py

    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'test', test),
    url(r'errand/make', errand.make),
    url(r'errand/preview', errand.preview)
]

# views/errand.py

@api_view(['GET'])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer, ))
def preview(request):
    e = Errand.objects.get(pk=request.GET['errand_id'])
    return Response({'data': e.get_preview_data()})
```

In order for this line

```
    e = Errand.objects.get(pk=request.GET['errand_id'])
```

To run fine, **errand_id** needs to be available. How can I check for certain *request keys* ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a `TypeError` on any function call where a parameter does not have a default value.

As long as you aren't passing in defaults, you'll get an exception, even if the parameter is never used inside the function.

In your example, since you use `dict.get`, by default if the key is not found it will return `None`

If you wanted an exception there, you could try directly accessing the key, which would result in a `KeyError` when it isn't found. Like so:

```
...
e = Errand.objects.get(pk=request['errand_id'])
...
```

Otherwise another solution would be to create a schema that represents the desired structure of the request, and validate the request either in the function or using a decorator.

Something like this would be a start:

```
def errand_id_required(func):
    def func_wrapper(request):
        if not request.get('errand_id', False):
            raise KeyError('errand_id not present in request')
        return func(request)
    return func_wrapper

@errand_id_required
def preview(request):
    e = Errand.objects.get(pk=request.GET['errand_id'])
    return Response({'data': e.get_preview_data()})
```

I would generally only do this if I had a sophisticated way of validating dictionary schemas, otherwise it's very much overkill to write a decorator to check a single key.

You could try the schema library on pypi, and define something like this:

```
import schema

errand_schema = {
    schema.Optional('some_key'): str,
    'id': int,
    'errand_id': int,
}
Errand = schema.Schema(errand_schema, ignore_extra_keys=True)
```

and you could use `Errand.validate(request)` instead of the `if.. raise KeyError` that I put in the decorator.

But I'll leave that up to you to decide upon...

Comment: Sure - that would be inferred params from the url right? Can you take a look my at edit. It might clear things up a little.

Comment: What if `errand_id ` is present but `Errand.objects.get(pk=request.GET['errand_id'])` raises `Errand.DoesNotExist` ?

Comment: Why would it raise an attribute of itself as an Exception?

Comment: If `Errand` do not contain any object with `pk=errand_id` then `Errand.objects.get` will raise `Errand.DoesNotExist`